# Urgent Issue: na78 instance not reachable. Any thoughts?

Tags: instance

Suddenly, this is what I am seeing when I tried to login into my Salesforce production. Any thoughts?

https://na78.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/alohaRedirect/701/o

[image]

Comment: Nothing on trust yet: https://status.salesforce.com/instances/NA78 - ruled your connection and/or network?

Comment: Doesn't seems related to Salesforce. Try check your connection, firewall, restart computer.

Comment: @LironC Thanks for the reply. It could be a flick from the Salesforce server. I have checked my internet connectivity and it was fine. I tried in other browser and got the same issue. Everything happened for just a few seconds.